# Flashing BLU Life One X2 Mini wiht Stock ROM

Tags: rom-flashing, twrp, stock-rom, nandroid, flashtool

I am experimenting with custom ROMs on my BLU Life One X2 Mini and had done the following:

- Unlock bootloader
- Root device
- Install TWRP
- Create a NANDroid backup

And was in the process of wiping the phone using TWRP to prep for the installation of LineageOS when my phone suddenly restarted.

It would appear that the wiping also cleared TWRP. I'm not sure why; I had specifically installed it on the recovery partition...

As a result, the phone now doesn't boot into Android, but it's still visible to my computer and as far as I know, I'm only able to flash it using QFIL.

I'm looking for options to either:
A) Use my TWRP backup and somehow deploy it from QFIL
B) Get a QFIL ROM that is made for Life One X2 Mini

Finding these is a pain with all the click bait websites and triple redirect download links..

Also if you know of any other alternative, I'd be happy to learn it.

Thanks

Comment: At this point, the only solution is to flash a stock firmware using QFIL.

Comment: Try this link: http://blox2.com/rom-stock-blu-life-one-x2-mini/ (not tested)

Comment: Thanks yeah I landed on that link before. Sadly all of its download links are broken

Comment: Which model is that phone? Is it the T470 model?

Comment: Try finding your phone firmware here: https://www.stockrom.net/blu

Comment: Thanks @esQmo_ even though that link only has a ROM for the non Mini version of the Life One X2, I took a chance and flashed it. It then allowed me to reinstall TWRP properly along with LineageOS, thanks!!

Comment: Glad you solved your problem.